# Is it possible to get estimation time to reach destination from Standard Google map navigation to our application?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, navigation

I am trying to develop an Android App that can open the Google Map navigation directly.
But I need to get estimation time to reach the destination on certain time interval so that my application can notify other users with estimation time.

Is this possible to do in Android? Thank you

Comment: There's no real API for that.  However you can register for GPS locations yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can open MainActivity on your application, launch google map intent, launch service that will keep track the locations updates and close activity. 
You need to do all your stuff with Service

Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
    Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=20.344,34.34&daddr=20.5666,45.345"));
startActivity(intent);

Comment: Basically, I want to use google map navigation and want to get the estimation time to reach to the destination.And on certain time interval, I need to send the notification to other users with his estimation time to reach a destination. Is this possible to get estimation time to reach destination?

Comment: http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/route-between-two-locations-with-waypoints-in-google-map-android-api-v2/

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#DirectionsRequests

You need to use google map api for android, get Json object with destination, time and more information about trip. 
Here is Json response example https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=33.3881725,-111.7897671&destination=33.3879013,-111.7890634

Comment: I want to use default Google Map app for navigation

Comment: You can't use google map application, you can use only Google Map API for android for creating your own application similar to google map.